# How can i use attribute_fu and treat the first element differently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `attribute_fu` with rails 2.2 and I would like to treat the first nested element differently than the rest, meaning I would like to render a different partial or pass a parameter to the existing partial.

Is that possible ?

Thanks,
Cezar

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question !

For those running into the same problem: you can pass a locals hash like you would pass it to a normal render :partial like so :

```
<%= f.render_associated_form(@your_model, :locals => {:var => value}) %>
```

Regards,
Cezar